# Draw an object in an array according to a vector

Tags: python, numpy, vector

Aim:

I am writing code to work out the angle between two 3D vectors (easy enough). However the vectors are defined according to an alignment of data carried out be a separate program. To be more precise the alignment program takes volumes and aligns them according to common features. These features are essentially a thick white line with a smaller line coming out of it in a very noisy greyscale image.

Using masks I am aligning the thick and smaller white lines separately then using the known rotations to put them back into the position they would have been in the original images and I can then work out the angle between them (a few thousand images).

Current problem:

Whilst I am fairly confident this works I want to test this by creating some sample data and running it through the alignment program and then through my code.

Making a 3D numpy array full of random greyscale numbers is easy to do in numpy using the code:

```
def RandomNoise():
NoiseArray = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,100,100))

return NoiseArray
```

I then need to somehow insert a thick white line and then a smaller white line at random angles coming from its centre. I guess i could add the thick white line as a plane across the whole 3D space that stays in that same position. I am just stuck in regard to place the thinner white line at random angles. I thought about defining it as a vector and applying random rotations to it, recording the rotations, and then rendering in the array as a cylinder, but I don't know how to go about this.

EDIT: to clarify the 'thick' white line is essentially just a white plane across the whole 3D space in Z with a defined height in x and y (say 20 pixels in a 100,100,100 array for example). The 'thin' white line is then a cylinder of defined radius (say 10 pixels in a 100,100,100 array) that I want to come out of the white plane at varying angles, so it should 'pivot' at one end on the thicker white line.

It is this white cylinder that I was thinking of defining as a vector and then using a rotation matrix to apply random rotations to before drawing into the 3D array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: requested sketch

[image]

Comment: So, IIUC, what you want is to generate 3D arrays with this "thick" and "thin" lines. It is still a bit unspecific. This (straight?) lines, are they like sort of "cilinders" (like a cable), or "strips", or something else? Are they fully white, or "fading" around the edges? How does the thin line exactly "come out" of the thick one (from origin, some point in the middle, ...)? Are the lines perfectly straight with constant thickness, and where do they start and end? I make a lot of questions because I suppose a visual representation of what you want may be hard to produce...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have edited the original comment with the paragraph below: to clarify the 'thick' white line is essentially just a white plane across the whole 3D space in Z with a defined heigh in x and y (say 20 pixels in a 100,100,100 array for example). The 'thin' white line is then a cylinder of defined radius (say 10 pixels in a 100,100,100 array) that I want to come out of the white plane at varying angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question is wasn't completely sure how the different lines should be aligned with respect to each other, but I'll provide you the following small script which should serve as a starting point in any case. For the rotation you can use [`rotate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) from the scipy package.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

np.random.seed(181003)

N = 100  # Number of images.
m, n = 100, 100  # row and column dimension.
test = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (N, m, n))

def create_bars(d):
    """Parameter d indicates thickness of the bar in number of rows"""
    bars = np.zeros((N, m, n), dtype=float)
    bars[:, m//2 - d : m//2 + d, :] = np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.0, (N, 2*d, n))
    for i, angle in enumerate(np.random.uniform(0, 180, N)):  # Angle in degrees.
        bars[i, :, :] = rotate(bars[i], angle, reshape=False)
    return bars

test += create_bars(m // 5)  # Thick bars.
test += create_bars(m // 25)  # Thin bars.

for i in range(3):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(test[i])
plt.show()
```

From the following example images you can see that the overlap region has more intensity than the rest of the bars. If that is undesired the tick and thin bars need to be created together and the overlap region can be taken care of.

[image: Example]

## Edit based on update of OP

We can generate the plane and cylinder by means of the corresponding indices for the 3D array. We can rotate these indices in order to get new indices for the rotated shapes (we need to center indices before rotation and then shift back again). Here is some example code:

```
"""Coordinate system is z, y, x for indexing the 3D array (i.e. test[z, y, x])."""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def rotate_z(angle):
    return np.array([
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
        [0, np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)],
    ])

def rotate_y(angle):
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(angle), 0, np.sin(angle)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(angle), 0, np.cos(angle)],
    ])

def rotate_x(angle):
    return np.array([
        [np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle), 0],
        [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle), 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
    ])

l = m = n = 40  # Use only small number of points due to plotting.
test = np.random.uniform(0, 0.95, (l, m, n))

d = l // 10  # Thickness of plane.
i_thick = np.array([*np.ndindex(d, m, n)]).T  # Indices for plane.
i_thick[0, :] -= d // 2
i_thick[1, :] -= m // 2
i_thick[2, :] -= n // 2

angle_y = angle_x = 0  # Angles about which the plane is rotated.
i_thick = rotate_y(angle_y) @ i_thick
i_thick = rotate_x(angle_x) @ i_thick
i_thick[0, :] += d // 2 + l // 2
i_thick[1, :] += m // 2
i_thick[2, :] += n // 2
i_thick = np.clip(np.round(i_thick).astype(int), 0, np.array(test.shape)[:, None] - 1)  # Correct rounding errors.

test[i_thick.tolist()] = np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.0, i_thick.shape[1])  # Add the plane.

r = m // 8  # Radius of cylinder.
i_cylinder = np.array([*np.ndindex(l, m, n)])
i_cylinder = i_cylinder[
    (i_cylinder[:, 0] < l // 2)
    & (np.sqrt((i_cylinder[:, 1] - m // 2)**2 + (i_cylinder[:, 2] - n // 2)**2) < r)
].T
i_cylinder[0, :] -= l // 2
i_cylinder[1, :] -= m // 2
i_cylinder[2, :] -= n // 2

# Align cylinder with plane.
i_cylinder = rotate_y(angle_y) @ i_cylinder
i_cylinder = rotate_x(angle_x) @ i_cylinder

angle2_z = angle2_y = angle2_x = 0  # Angles about which the cylinder is rotated.
i_cylinder = rotate_z(angle2_z) @ i_cylinder
i_cylinder = rotate_y(angle2_y) @ i_cylinder
i_cylinder = rotate_x(angle2_x) @ i_cylinder

i_cylinder[0, :] += l // 2
i_cylinder[1, :] += m // 2
i_cylinder[2, :] += n // 2
i_cylinder = np.clip(np.round(i_cylinder).astype(int), 0, np.array(test.shape)[:, None] - 1)

test[i_cylinder.tolist()] = np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.0, i_cylinder.shape[1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
test_plot = test.copy()
test_plot = np.moveaxis(test_plot, [0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1])  # Reorder axes from `z, y, x` to `y, x, z` in order to be aligned with plt.scatter.
test_plot = np.flip(test_plot, axis=2)  # Flip along `z` in order to plot top-to-bottom rather than bottom-to-top.
ax.scatter(*np.array([*np.ndindex(m, n, l)]).T[:, test_plot.ravel() >= 0.95].tolist(), s=1)
ax.set_xlim([0, test.shape[1] - 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, test.shape[0] - 1])
ax.set_zlim([0, test.shape[2] - 1])
plt.show()
```

For example both shapes not rotated:

[image: Example 3D no rotation]

Another example for plane rotated around `x` by `-pi/2` and cylinder additionally rotated around `z` and `x` by `pi/8`:

[image: Example 3D with rotation]

Comment: I think this goes in the good direction, but my understanding is that the OP wants to produce 3D arrays representing a volume (where each value is a color, like a structure of voxels) with the lines embedded in it, not a collection of 2D images.

Comment: Thank you this is pointing me in the right direction I think. jdehesa is right though in the end I need this is a 3D volume and I need the 'thin bar' to be pivoting at one end on the 'thick bar'. This may however work if I lock the thick bar in place.

Comment: @Jt246 Could you maybe add a sketch to your question, so the desired structure becomes clear. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: @a_guest I tried, it isn't great but I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: @Jt246 Thanks, that helped a lot :) I updated my answer, it was a bit tricky, but I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks so much! I manage to use your previous solution to create the noisy image but was struggling with rotation. The new way seems to be working EXCEPT for the graphing. I haven't platted a graph using the np operations in the scatter command before (novice) but it is giving an error of needing an axis argument with flip. I am also uncertain as to why you are flipping?

Comment: @Jt246 You are right, my intention was to plot the 3D array as represented by numpy (that is rows from top to bottom, columns from left to right and the third dimension from front to back). However `plt.scatter` uses a different ordering. The first dimension goes along the columns, the second front-to-back and the third bottom-to-top (not top-to-bottom). So actually we need to roll the axes back by 1 so they are in the order `y, x, z` (note that originally the array was indexed by `test[z, y, x]`). Then we need to flip along `z` in order to get top-to-bottom. I updated the snippet accordingly.